# Google Apps Script - Dynamically Add Remove UiApp Form Elements

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to create a Ui form section in my application that will Dynamically Add Remove UiApp Form Elements. I was trying to use the example from App Script Tutorials [here](http://www.googleappsscript.org/miscellaneous/creating-form-elements-dynamically-using-google-apps-script-gas)

This example works great as far as performing the add remove elements, but when I use the submit button to capture the values, it submits as a `JSON.stringify` format. When I just want to capture the values only in a text or string format that will be added to a html email.

If there is way to convert `JSON.stringify` to text, string or get the values only in format, I will continue to use this example.

If not I was wonder if the following Javascript HTML code can be convert into GAS code and able to capture the values for each entry in a HTML email template to using in `MailApp`.

http://jsfiddle.net/g59K7/

Any suggestions, examples or adjustments to the codes would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Are you using UiApp or not? On UiApp there's no client-side code to for you `stringify` or whatever. Also, if you want to use HTML code use [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) instead of UiApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the result to be in a JSON object, then you can adjust the _processSubmittedData(e) function. Right now he has it writing everything to an Object, which is fine. All you have to do is have a way to parse it:

```
  function _processSubmittedData(e){
  var result = {};
  result.groupName = e.parameter.groupName;
  var numMembers = parseInt(e.parameter.table_tag);
  result.members = []; 
  //Member info array
  for(var i=1; i<=numMembers; i++){
        var member = {};
        member.firstName = e.parameter['fName'+i];
        member.lastName = e.parameter['lName'+i];
        member.dateOfBirth = e.parameter['dob'+i];
        member.note = e.parameter['note'+i];
        result.members.push(member);
  }

  var htmlBody = 'Group Name: ' + result.groupName;
  for(var a in result.members) {
    var member = result.members[a];
    var date = member.dateOfBirth;
    var last = member.lastName;
    var first = member.firstName;
    var note = member.note;

    htmlBody += first + ' ' + last + ' was born on ' + date + ' and has this note: ' + note;
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail('fakeEmail@fake.com',"Test Subject Line", "", {htmlBody: htmlBody});
    }
```

Comment: Hello Stan, thank so much for the help. I have an issue when I add the adjusted code to the master sheet code. I receive undefined values. I have a test spreadsheet with both codes. In the script editor you will see Working Code and Not Working Code - Undefined for Address. Can see what I am doing wrong or if I placed the code in the wrong place. [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1adXbsUp2T0DroWhern1oU4oaKszO37X7spBKiImYC8Y/edit#gid=1138046975